# Where are the Nuremberg gallows?

Tags: nazi-germany

My google fu was weak - I was not able to find out where the Nuremberg gallows went after use. Were they destroyed, as a symbolic "It will never happen again, we don't need them anymore"? (Ha.) Or did they land in a museum?

Comment: It is commonplace for wooden gallows to be dismantled after usage and new ones build when needed later.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: In your comment, are you sure that "*and new ones build when needed later.*" is correct, rather than say "*re-erected again later when needed*"? It would seem that keeping the timber around as long as executions are performed periodically is more sensible than complete reconstruction each time.

Comment: *'we don't need them anymore"? (Ha.)'* -- Well It seems no war-criminals have been tried and executed in Europe in the last 70 years.

Comment: *Where are the Nuremberg gallows ?* - Why ? Do you plan on acquiring them for your own private and personal version of a Nazi Golgotha, and treasuring them with the same reverence devout Christians usually give to the wood of the original cross ? Or plan on later reselling them to someone who might ?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Often the space was needed for other things. In the case of Nürnberg 1946 the room was a gym used by the US army. Later executions were, I believe, done elsewhere (Landsburg).

Comment: @MarkJohnson: That's not my question. You specify "*rebuilt*" and I ask if "*re-erected*" is more accurate.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Reerected would imply reusing the existing parts. I don't believe that was the case in general, where executions were not an everyday affair. Tyburn was a permanent structure, but during the years often replaced.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Yet you clearly state, without evidence( or, apparently, research) "*rebuilt*". You may be correct - but you apparently don't know if you are, and neither do I. A dismantled gallows would be pretty compact. What would be the reason(s) for rebuilding every time?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Pre 1800 in Berlin, the hanging area was outside the city where the main wood source for the city was. It was later moved further out when the area had been deforested. The reports of the day announced when it would happened since the public took the day off to attend since they needed time to get there and back. It was not done in a public square as was done later when beheading replaced hanging. The reports (newspapers) never mentioned how they were built or dismanteled.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Apart from all your valid objections, just 1 thing: _that_ one apparatus from Oct46 was as dysfunctionally botched like a ronavax, killed improperly, so 0 reason to re-use it 'as was' at all. Look at the photos of the executed, quite bloody? Eg: Trap door was too small, so they banged their heads in; height was wrong, so they didn't break a neck but strangled to death too often. Quite an unlucky machine.

Comment: @LаngLаngС: It's surprisingly difficult to get the correct "*drop*" for each individual so as to neither decapitate nor leave hanging; but the tradition has been to err on the latter side, leading to the phrasing of the sentence as: "*hang by the neck until dead*". Only a very experienced *hangman* can get the "*drop*" correct with any consistency. That has nothing to do with the gallows, but rather depends on the length of rope.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens …yep & the height, weight of the 'hangee', rope thickness… 'Length of rope' _chosen_ was surely also influenced by 'whole construction' (looks…) But still, the door alone was just wrong, too small. [Aside: what morbid math use…]

Comment: Eye witness account: [The Nuremberg Trials: The Execution of Nazi War Criminals KINGSBURY SMITH / International News Service 16oct1946](https://web.archive.org/web/20060222022612/http://www.mindfully.org/Reform/Nazi-Execution-Smith16oct46.htm)

Comment: @Lucian They're important historical artefacts; is it really so strange for the OP to wonder what happened to them afterwards?

Comment: @nick012000: There is nothing strange about historical musings; then again, there's nothing strange about shrines either; all cities have a cathedral, all villages have a church.

Comment: at both: I can't deny that the thought occured to me - in current Germany, they could at least be used as a "friendly remainder" showpiece for what tends to happens to Nazis (even if those new Übermenschs couldn't win a world war against Luxembourg and we don't have death penalty anyway). And yes, I guess they would indeed net a nice price on Ebay...